# Simulating keyboard actions using casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

How to simulate the keyboard actions/events using casperjs?. I am stuck while pressing keyboard actions like `shift + alt + enter`, `ctrl + }` and `ctrl + shift + >` and many more like these..
can some one help me with these kind of actions

tried with the following

```
this.sendKeys('div.edit-code > textarea:nth-child(1)', 'enter', {modifiers: 'shift + alt'});
```

### EDIT :

I need to execute the cell using keyboard shortcuts for [this site](https://rcloud.social/login.R) and the scenario is like following:

- Create a new cell using `'+'` sign
- add some contents to the cell
- Now using keyboard shortcut, need to execute(for eg: `"shift+alt+enter"` the cell

Answer (score 1):

I write a small test case:

**keyboard.html**(Catch keyboard event and write it to a div):

```
<script>
    document.onkeypress = function (e) {
        var keys = [e.ctrlKey ? "CTRL" : "", e.altKey ? "ALT" : "", e.shiftKey ? "SHIFT" : "", String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)].filter(function (x) {
            return x != "";
        })
        document.querySelector('#text').textContent = keys.join(" + ");
    };
</script>
<div id="text">

</div>
```

**Casper script**:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://localhost:63344/CasperSheet/keyboard.html');

function testKey(key, modifiers) {
    casper.then(function () {
        casper.sendKeys("#text", key, {modifiers: modifiers});
    }).then(function () {
        casper.echo(casper.evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelector("#text").textContent
        }))
    })
}

testKey('a');
testKey('}', 'ctrl')
testKey('>', 'ctrl+alt')
testKey('\n', 'shift+alt')
casper.run();
```

**Output**:

```
a
CTRL + }
CTRL + ALT + >
ALT + SHIFT + 
//a new line here...
```

---

Come to your code, my suggestion:

1. `'enter'` should be `'\n'`. If you use `'enter'`, it will send `'e'`, `'n'`, `'t'`, `'e'`, `'r'` five key board events...
2. `{modifiers: 'shift + alt'}` should be `{modifiers: 'shift+alt'}`. Because the implementation of modifiers combo doesn't trim space... You can post a pull request to CasperJS to fix that...

---

Okay, let's us discuss how to run your code in that web app... I found we can run code by click the `play` button, so there is no need to run code by  `alt + shift + enter` which is very hard to implement...

That script works for me:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1600,
        height: 900
    }
});

var cookie = "user=Sayalic0; token=<some_token>";
var domain = "rcloud.social";
cookie.split(";").forEach(function(pair){
    pair = pair.split("=");
    phantom.addCookie({
        'name': pair[0],
        'value': pair[1],
        'domain': domain
    });
});


casper.start('https://rcloud.social/edit.html?notebook=<note_book_id>')

casper.then(function () {
    casper.wait(30000);//wait for page load
}).then(function () {
    casper.capture('1.png')
}).then(function () {
    casper.click("#run-notebook > i")// click run
}).then(function () {
    casper.wait(10000)//wait code running ends
}).then(function () {
    casper.capture('2.png');
})

casper.run()
```

**screenshot**:

**1.png**
[image]

**2.png**
[image]